# What is posthistory?

Tags: support, data-dump

I am trying to use Stack Overflow offline and I see that there are 2 files names Posts and PostHistory in archive.org available for downloads. Can someone tell me what PostHistory is?

1. Is it all the discussion indented below each answer of the question?
2. Is it something else: for example all the changes over time to the question and the answers and the comment to the answers?
3. Is it the content of deleted questions and answers?

I am only interested to have all the current questions, answers and comments to the answers: would downloading Posts be sufficient for this?